# frontend for d3.js with data binding

Tags: d3.js

Can anyone recommend a frontend for d3.js with data binding. For example I click on buttons  on my frontend and it changes parts of my d3.js chart. Or I click on my d3 chart, and additional data pop up on my table.

I thought React would be a good choice, but I hardly see any tutorials to bind the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular, Vue or React, any front-end framework will work good as well.

Just catch the click events that are going to modify the chart and use a function to refresh the chart so you bind it to the click.

Something like (i.e vue):

```
<button @click="update()">Update Values</button>
```

And in the methods:

```
    update: function() { 
       //Do the changes over the data here and then call the render function
       this.renderChart() 
    }


    renderChart: function() {
       // All the d3 code here to build the chart with updated data
    }
```